# How to sort by event date asc when query is in descending order MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column name 'dateEvent' in MySQL which stores date in the format 'Y-m-d':

```
+-------------+
| dateEvent   |
|-------------+
| 2018-01-01  |
| 2022-01-02  |
| 2021-01-03  |
| 2019-01-04  |
| 2016-01-05  |
| 2018-01-06  |
| 2020-01-07  |
| 2017-01-08  |
| 2021-01-09  |
| 2015-01-10  |
| 2016-01-11  |
| 2019-01-12  |
| 2018-01-13  |
| 2021-01-14  |
+-------------+
```

I need to output 3 nearest day right before today (6-jan) regardless of the year (5-jan, 4-jan and 3-jan) and they be sorted in ascending order (3-jan, 4-jan, 5-jan)

My query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DAYOFYEAR(dateEvent) < DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) ORDER BY DAYOFYEAR(dateEvent) DESC LIMIT 3")
```

Output:

```
2016-01-05 |                      | 2021-01-03
2019-01-04 | -->I want there are: | 2019-01-04
2021-01-03 |                      | 2016-01-05
```

When i change ORDER to ASC, output is

```
2018-01-01 |
2022-01-02 |  incorrect with my request
2021-01-03 |
```

How can I do? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Will `31-dec` be a nearest day to `01-jan`?

Comment: Yes, ProGu, that's what i need

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Can you run `SELECT version();` to check?

Comment: MySQL version is 5.7.21, FanoFN

Comment: Have you tried the posted answers below? If you have, is it your expected result? If it's not, can you update your question with the details of your findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the probably simplest way is to just get the `LIMIT`ing done in a derived table and apply another `ORDER BY` in the outer query.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM elbat
                    WHERE dayofyear(dateevent) < dayofyear(curdate())
                    ORDER BY dayofyear(dateevent) DESC
                    LIMIT 3) AS x
       ORDER BY dayofyear(dateevent) ASC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b7f8b9f7b025747141c04952b08584ed)

Comment: My problem is solved, thanks sticky bit!

Comment: @bin2003: Then consider accepting (green check mark) and up voting (arrow pointing up) the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to order by:

```
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(dateEvent, '%m-%d')
```

or

```
ORDER BY MONTH(dateEvent), DAYOFMONTH(dateEvent)
```